# How can Jack and Sally have children?

Tags: the-nightmare-before-christmas

In the epilogue of the official *The Nightmare Before Christmas* soundtrack, it says this:

> With four or five skeleton children at hand
>
> Playing strange little tunes in their xylophone band

It is obviously implied that these are Jack and Sally's children but how is it possible for them to reproduce?

Comment: Why would it not be possible for them to reproduce?

Comment: You'll suspend your disbelief for the existence of a Christmas-loving skeleton and a reanimated corpse, but draw the line at their ability to reproduce?

Comment: When a skeleton man loves a rotting amalgum of undead female flesh very much...

Comment: Simple: Adoption.

Answer (score 7):

Even within the context of their fictional world, the inhabitants of Halloweentown are conceptual entities, products of the imagination.  They could very well have imagined their offspring into existence.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume either some Halloween magic or sally's dad. The evil scientist did create her so I'm sure he could find a way to spawn their children through some weird experiment.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this by editing it to include any evidence you know that would support either of these explanations.